# Struts 2 : Displays table of Songs - null gets printed

Tags: java, list, jsp, struts2, iterator

I am trying to populate a html table of songs with the following fields.

**Song Name**, **Album Name**

In order to do that I am already sending **List** of **Song** objects to the JSP from my struts 2 action class. The following is the structure of the Song and Album Classes.

```
  Song
  ----
      Title:String
      album: Album

  Album
  -----
      title : String
      releasedYear:int
```

The problem here is , when i try to iterate through the **allSongs** list, I am able to print the Song name, But it doesnt print the album name. The following is my JSP code written using struts tags.

```
<table width="500px">
    <s:iterator value="allSongs">
     <tr>
        <td><s:property value="Title" /></td> // this is getting printed
        <td><s:property value="album.title" /></td>   // this doesnt get printed
     </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

I tried to use the below code in the JSP to find the issue. But it shows null as the output.

```
System.out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("album")
```

Could you please anyone help me on this? If the information provided not sufficient, Please let me know , I will update the question. Thanks in advance.

Note: I checked the list before it get passed to the JSP, the values are properly populated there.

### Action Class

```
public class HomeAction {

    private List<Song> allSongs;

    public List<Song> getAllSongs() {
            return allSongs;
    }

    public void setAllSongs(List<Song> allSongs) {
            this.allSongs = allSongs;
    }

    private MusicManager musicManager;

    public MusicManager getMusicManager() {
            return musicManager;
    }

    public void setMusicManager(MusicManager musicManager) {
            this.musicManager = musicManager;
    }

    // all struts logic here
    public String displayAllSongs() {
            allSongs = musicManager.listAllSongs();
            return "SUCCESS";

    }
}
```

### Song Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Song", catalog = "myFavMusic")
public class Song implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Album album;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Singer singer;

    private Integer rating;

    //getter setters
}
```

### Album Class

```
@Entity
public class Album implements Serializable {

    public Album() {
            super();
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "album")
    private List<Song> songs = null;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ALBUM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    // album or song , this could be replaced with enum later
    @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "RELEASED_YEAR", nullable = false)
    private Integer releasedYear;
//getter setters
}
```

Comment: Please share the form that you are using and the action class

Comment: That should work as you have it, try doing `System.out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("album.title")` within your iterator and see what the result is.

Comment: I tried as you said Dan, it prints null as well

Comment: Can you post the Action class as well as the Song and Album classes?

Comment: Post your code as text, not as images. And post it. The code you posted is incomplete. What matters are the bean properties, i.e. getters.

Comment: Can you post code for `MusicManager` and also can you post the code as text and not images?

Comment: Share the execute() method in Action class and the form from where you are giving the input data as well.

Comment: I don't see `Title` in your Song entity; in page, the one that gets printed should be `title`, not `Title`. Are you sure the circular reference `Song` containinig `Album` containing a `List<Song>` is not breaking something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The Song class did not have getter method for the album property. As JB Nizet said , I checked the getters and setters of all the classes and That solved the problem. Thank you all.

To Identify the problem, I used the scriptlet blocks inside the jsp and wrote the java code to figure out the problem. When i tried to write song.getAlbum() line , I found that there was no  getAlbum method defined in the song class.

```
    List<com.myprojects.myfavmusic.domain.Song> allSongs =(List<com.myprojects.myfavmusic.domain.Song>)pageContext.findAttribute("allSongs");
    for (com.myprojects.myfavmusic.domain.Song song : allSongs) {  
            System.out.println(song.getAlbum().getTitle());
}
```